# Loading images with alphablending

Tags: python, image, png, pygame, alpha

First of all, excuse me for my bad english for now on. I'm not a good english writter.

I am making a little game con pygame (on python3), under Windows 7. And I am experimenting with images (png) and it's alpha channel. 
I have a little question: what is the more efficient way to work with alphablending? Using png's file with alpha defined in it, or setting alpha value from code? Why?
Is there any info about this?

Advanced thanks for help. And again, sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
your_image = pygame.image.load('image_name.png').convert_alpha()
```

However, it is better if your image already has its alpha defined. To be certain, however, just add `.convert_alpha()` as shown above

Comment: @user3426347, Well, did that help?

Comment: Hi! Yeah, actually my answer was to known if it's better to have an image with alpha defined. Thanks for the answer!
I found a "profiler" to see what parts of the code go slowly, so i think this will help me to see what are the best ways next time.
Thanks, i appreciate your help!